# Change the file upload progress bar behavior in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `Shiny` application that requires the user to upload multiple small text files, I do this with `fileInput`. When I upload multiple files, the progress bar seems to half reset after each file is uploaded in turn. This looks very messy and I'd prefer it if the bar simply showed how many files had finished uploading rather than the progress of any individual file.

[Here is a gif of the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB15n.jpg):

**My question is**: Is there a way using base `Shiny` to change the behavior of the upload progress bar for `fileInput`? And if not, are there any other packages that could be used?

Here is an example of using `fileInput`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("File Input Progress Bar Demo"),
  fileInput(
    inputId = "MyFiles",
    label = "Upload multiple files",
    multiple = T
  ),
  mainPanel()
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe this would be useful https://gist.github.com/markheckmann/8314905

Comment: I don't think so, that example seems to reset the bar _after_ it has finished uploading. I'm concerned with the bar's behavior during upload.

Comment: If you're out of ideas, check `withProgress()` function from Shiny, maybe there is a way to apply it to the `fileInput` somehow, though I doubt it.